# Ruby RuntimeError on launching terminal (Mac)

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal, ruby

Whenever I open the terminal on Mac I get this error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: invalid option --1  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)
```

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/3y0D2r3V410Y
.bash_profile: http://cl.ly/image/232J1z183R09

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: What does `$RUBYOPT` contain on your system?

Comment: You source in a file `~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`, what is probably related to the Ruby version manager. Check this file.

Comment: Apparently the problem was with brew.rb from Homebrew. I replaced it with the one from their git repo and ran 'brew update'. Everything seems to be fine now.